# RetryExecutor : How to wait for all tasks to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using RetryExecutor from : https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry

Below id my code :

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
RetryExecutor retryExecutor = new AsyncRetryExecutor(executorService)
            .retryOn(IOException.class)
            .withExponentialBackoff(500, 2)
            .withMaxDelay(5_000) // 5 seconds
            .withUniformJitter()
            .withMaxRetries(5);
```

I have submitted a few tasks to retryExecutor.

```
retryExecutor.getWithRetry(ctx -> {
                if(ctx.getRetryCount()==0)
                    System.out.println("Starting download from : " + url);
                else
                    System.out.println("Retrying ("+ctx.getRetryCount()+") dowload from : "+url);
                return downloadFile(url);
            }
        ).whenComplete((result, error) -> {
            if(result!=null && result){
                System.out.println("Successfully downloaded!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Download failed. Error : "+error);
            }
        });
```

Now, how do I wait for all submitted tasks to finish?
I want to wait until all retries are finished (if any).

don't think it will be as simple as executorService.shutdown();

Answer (score -1):

`CompletableFuture<DownloadResult> downloadPromise = 
        retryExecutor.getWithRetry(...)
                     .whenComplete(...);
DownloadResult downloadResult = downloadPromise.get()`

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)